# Not able to send C2DM message to device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android and I'm trying to develop push notification in my app.

I had read so many post and able to generate device registration key and authentication key.

but when I'm trying to send push notification message to device i got following message.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and following is php code which I'm using to send message:

```
function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) {

$headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
$data = array(
    'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
    'collapse_key' => $msgType,
    'data.message' => $messageText //TODO Add more params with just simple data instead           
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
if ($headers)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response); die;

}

sendMessageToPhone($auth_token, $device_id , "UTF-8","hello");
```

I had also enable "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" service by emaid which I had used to generate authentication token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong way because you tried to work with G2DM. G2DM is deprecated.

This is great tutorial for GCM. You can set up the push notification in 30 minutes. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Hi mferhan,

thanks a lot.
now it's working fine for me. this article is really useful.

thanks